# In Photos app, how do I group thumbnails together?

Tags: ios, photos

Is there any way to group selected thumbnails together under a single thumbnail, similar to Stacks in Adobe Bridge and Lightroom?

I know you can stack photos together temporarily to share them (see the video link below); I’d like to make the stack permanent to save space.

https://youtube.com/clip/Ugkx9hWGFxKaL_YTtfJ6sCRBC-zv59dVJXh3?si=TfMWqOBrL4V4xHx8

Answer (score 0):

The only manual grouping that Photos supports is Albums, which I'm sure you're familiar with.

There is no way to create folders or stacks in the main photos view.